# Java sub-process command line execution with/without cmd.exe

Tags: java, windows, cmd, subprocess

My question consists of several things I don't understand about the use of "cmd.exe", "/c" when executing sub-processes from Java in Windows. Basically, I couldn't find a good explanation about when and why they're needed.
My specific problems: I have a small framework for sub-processes execution. One use is a Java application which "manages" several other JVMs created by ProcessBuilders. One of the key requirements is that when a sub-process is stuck, or the hosting application is terminating, it must be able to kill the sub-processes.
The problem is, on one hand, doing this:

```
new ProcessBuilder("java", "...").start();
```

Causes this:

```
Could not find or load main class ...
```

As if the system variables or directory are different (which they're not). On the other hand, wrapping it in a cmd.exe like this:

```
new ProcessBuilder("cmd.exe", "/c", "java", "...").start();
```

WORKS, but creates another cmd.exe process, which has a side effect: the child JVM is now a sub-sub-process, and `process.destroy();` doesn't kill it (a known bug in the Windows JRE as I found).
This specific problem was handled on a different level, since all those applications are ours and we know their PIDs. But it's an example how cmd.exe makes everything work differently (or prevent the JVM from working at all). So I'd like to know what exactly happens there.
Here the framework itself comes into the picture as well. It's also going to be used by our testing platform. I'd like to provide an API which allows wrapping the command with a cmd.exe /c by a parameter. But, what exactly is the meaning of that parameter? How do the users decide if they want a cmd.exe wrapping?
AND a bonus I'd appreciate: is any of this relevant in other OS? Does it have some kind of an equivalent, say, in Linux?

Comment: cmd /c is going to make use of some environment variables like CLASSPATH and PATH, while calling java directly is going to get the environment from the parent process. This may explain the difference in behavior. Find out the differences between your process environment and cmd environment.

Comment: The applications need exactly the same variables, so it's strange. By the way, the java ... command contains the required variables. Does the absence of an enclosing cmd.exe somehow cause them to be ignored? Anyway, it was just an example, but this is kind of what the question is about: what does this wrapping do exactly? Environment, output, return value etc. I didn't find the answer yet.

Comment: The main things you get from using cmd is variable substitution and batch file support (so you can call a batch file instead of an executable), in my experience.

Comment: You don't need it to call a batch file (even if this batch file calls Java).

Comment: @JPMoresmau: the cmd.exe instance will *also* get its environment variables from the parent process, so that shouldn't make any difference.  My guess is that this is related to Java 8's use of symbolic links from the directory on the PATH to the actual executable.  (Depends a bit on what ProcessBuilder does under the hood.)

Answer (score 3):

Came across it again and found the problem, and some additional insights.

@HarryJohnston - good point, according to the javadoc the sub-process inherits the environment from both `ProcessBuilder` and `Runtime.getRuntime.exec(...)` APIs so it's not the issue (and java.exe is in fact found so PATH is obviously available).

But it seems certain command line features are lost. Among others it's this kind of *%VARIABLE%* usage in command line - they're not interpreted unless the command starts with `cmd.exe /c`.

In this case of class not found (it could also cause NoClassDefFoundError), I had several variables used in the classpath (perhaps I should have posted the entire command, but it's kinda long). When I replaced them with the literary paths, everything worked.

Basically:

`java -cp %classpath% Main` - bad

`cmd.exe /c java -cp %classpath% Main` - good

`java -cp D:\proj\bin Main` - good

So, on the **general question** of how's the behavior different with cmd.exe:

1. Variable references like this: %VARIABLE% are only interpreted by cmd.exe.
2. With cmd.exe you don't really need to split the command into String array of parameters, you can use one long String (array of "cmd.exe", "/c", "the rest...").
3. The sub-process will be cmd.exe and not the actual executable, so `process.destroy()` won't kill it. This might be a bug fixed in later versions (I used Java 7 and 8, Windows 7 and Server 2012).
4. File associations only work with cmd.exe, so you can't "execute" a file that is not a program or script ("CreateProcess error=193, %1 is not a valid Win32 application"). Calling executables defined in PATH does work.
5. `start` and `call` are only available under cmd.exe.
6. Command level errors behave differently as well: With cmd.exe the error will just be in the output stream, whereas without it the API throws an **exception**, which might also have a slightly different description.

   For example:

   `nothing` will cause *java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified*

   `cmd.exe /c nothing` will return output: *'nothing' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file*, and a return value of 1 (the only indication something went wrong).

On the deeper question of **why**, and is this the full list of differences, I still don't really know. Looks like the JVM has its way of running commands, which you can "wrap" with cmd.exe for additional features and protection.

Another interesting fact is when you run a Batch, it's actually run under a cmd.exe (with all its features). From my tests it seems `process.destroy()` can only kill it if it's not waiting for anything external (if stuck on `pause` for example), with or without additional cmd.exe /c wrapping, but not if it runs a sub-process - which is consistent with the cmd.exe limitation mentioned in point 3.

Comment: Good answer, but I do have a few nits to pick.  Re 2. you shouldn't need to split the command when using a ProcessBuilder either, according to the documentation you can use a String instead of a List of Strings.  In Windows, I always recommend using a single string, because that's what actually happens under the hood - a list will be converted to a single string before being executed, and sometimes the conversion is buggy.  Re 3. I don't think that's a bug, the documentation doesn't promise that children of the target process will be killed.

Comment: The why for all of this isn't particularly complicated, ProcessBuilder is using the Windows API to create a new process directly, not at all the same thing as having `cmd.exe` interpret a command line and create a new process for you.  No `cmd.exe` features are available if you create the process directly, e.g., variable substitution, using `|` as a pipe, `<` to redirect input, `&` to run multiple commands in a single line, and so on.  On the other hand, you also don't have to worry as much about special characters, and of course it is significantly more efficient.

Comment: Thnx. #2 - don't really remember about the splitting, maybe my test fd something up. #5 - removed the .exe. But I did managed to run `cmd.exe /c start notepad` which starts notepad. Didn't know about the other features, but the point of cmd.exe is clearer now. Thnx again!